# Wiring replacement AC contactor

Tags: air-conditioning

My air conditioner replacement contactor has terminals labelled L1, L2 and T1, T2. Are the L terminals the line in (power) and the T terminals the output that goes to the compressor and fan? Its part is c25bnb230t and is made by Eaton.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the datasheet. The full part number will identify which one you have:
http://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/772fae44f4baf4fd6f22e9b824e60f47.pdf

I had to do some googling myself to ensure that the "T" side is the LOAD. The "L" side is your Line end.

Comment: "L" is always the incoming line and "T" is always the load or outgoing side.

Comment: I'd advise strongly against that advice @d.george, STRONGLY.... all ti takes is one "cheap" vendor or knockoff vendor to get it wrong or change a convention, and then your use of "always" will not apply. It is best to always trust but verify.